How do set up cross compiling environment with openwrt?
I want to set up a cross-compilation environment for OpenWRT on Ubuntu 20.04.
So I followed these steps:
get install gcc g++ binutils patch bzip2 flex bison make autoconf gettext texinfo unzip sharutils subversion libncurses5-dev ncurses-term zlib1g-dev libssl-dev python git

git clone https://git.lede-project.org/source.git openwrt && cd openwrt

git checkout openwrt-18.06

./scripts/feeds update -a
./scripts/feeds install -a

make menuconfig

And then
make -j3 V=s

but occurred error like this:
make[8]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[8]: Leaving directory '/root/work/openwrt/build_dir/host/patch-2.7.6/lib'
make[7]: Leaving directory '/root/work/openwrt/build_dir/host/patch-2.7.6/lib'
make[6]: Leaving directory '/root/work/openwrt/build_dir/host/patch-2.7.6/lib'
Making install in src
make[6]: Entering directory '/root/work/openwrt/build_dir/host/patch-2.7.6/src'
make[7]: Entering directory '/root/work/openwrt/build_dir/host/patch-2.7.6/src'
make[7]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/root/work/openwrt/staging_dir/host/bin'
  /usr/bin/install -c patch '/root/work/openwrt/staging_dir/host/bin'
make[7]: Leaving directory '/root/work/openwrt/build_dir/host/patch-2.7.6/src'
make[6]: Leaving directory '/root/work/openwrt/build_dir/host/patch-2.7.6/src'
Making install in tests
make[6]: Entering directory '/root/work/openwrt/build_dir/host/patch-2.7.6/tests'
make[7]: Entering directory '/root/work/openwrt/build_dir/host/patch-2.7.6/tests'
make[7]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
make[7]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[7]: Leaving directory '/root/work/openwrt/build_dir/host/patch-2.7.6/tests'
make[6]: Leaving directory '/root/work/openwrt/build_dir/host/patch-2.7.6/tests'
make[6]: Entering directory '/root/work/openwrt/build_dir/host/patch-2.7.6'
make[7]: Entering directory '/root/work/openwrt/build_dir/host/patch-2.7.6'
make[7]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
 /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/root/work/openwrt/staging_dir/host/share/man/man1'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 'patch.man' '/root/work/openwrt/staging_dir/host/share/man/man1/patch.1'
make[7]: Leaving directory '/root/work/openwrt/build_dir/host/patch-2.7.6'
make[6]: Leaving directory '/root/work/openwrt/build_dir/host/patch-2.7.6'
make[5]: Leaving directory '/root/work/openwrt/build_dir/host/patch-2.7.6'
make[4]: Leaving directory '/root/work/openwrt/build_dir/host/patch-2.7.6'
mkdir -p /root/work/openwrt/staging_dir/host/stamp
touch /root/work/openwrt/build_dir/host/patch-2.7.6/.built
touch /root/work/openwrt/staging_dir/host/stamp/.patch_installed
make[3]: Leaving directory '/root/work/openwrt/tools/patch'
time: tools/patch/compile#38.96#11.63#105.54
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/work/openwrt'
make[1]: *** [tools/Makefile:150: /root/work/openwrt/staging_dir/target-mips_24kc_musl/stamp/.tools_compile_yynyyyyynyyyyynyynnyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyynyynynyyyynnyy] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/work/openwrt'
make: *** [/root/work/openwrt/include/toplevel.mk:218: world] Error 2

I'm gonna set up a cross-compilation environment for OpenWRT on Ubuntu 20.04.
I have a GL-SFT1200 and I am going to modify the source code and deploy it to the device.
